# PCM voice data on serial port to sound device conversion in linux

Tags: linux, audio, serial-port, modem, pcm

I have a telephony modem which gives voice to my interfaced application via a serial USB ttyUSB0 in 16bit PCM 8000hz. I am able to capture this data and play with audacity. I want this port to be detected as a sound device in linux (I am on ubuntu). Is it possible? Are there any other options?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are using a huawei 3G modem or something similar which gives ttyUSB1 for audio. Make sure you have the serial driver binded to it. Then simply pass the port itself as a "file" for input for any program of your choice.You need root access for that.You figured out the audio settings so it must be enough.I have  voice calling working in UBUNTU 11.10 with Huawei. So let me know if i can help any further.

Comment: Hello Sai I have a SICOM modem (almost the same as huwaei 3G you have mentioned). I am able to read write into the modem just with following commands in voice calls

Comment: with 5 usb ports. I am able to read write into the modem just with following commands in voice calls  `cat /dev/ttyUSB0 > record.raw`  and cat /dev/ttyUSB0 < record.raw..  Its just elementary and I need to issue parallel AT commands in ttyUSB2. How do you make full fledged voice  calling? did u find or write any application like mobile partner?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I see it's very old question but answers helped me to get a right direction so I decided to help others.

1. The one way to achieve (in addition to below) what are you are
   looking for is to write dynamic kernel module.
2. Have it register as a sound device, and check that it has a GSM
   module present (which module is it exactly can be recognized in
   `dmesg`, `lsmod`, or `output`).
3. Then establish communication between user space representation as a
   sound card and serial usb module.

The other way is to get module that you recognized by `dmesg`, `lsmod` and extend its functionality as a sound card.

All are tricky tasks because:

- in the first case you have to resolve intermodule communication at the kernel level...... which is, lets say, a little hard even if programmer has a right background in subject.
- the second case is hard in that you have to deal with:

  - USB stack (which is little unpleasant for human beings) and
  - sound subsystem (which is a little burdensome because of historical issues).

Without being an experienced kernel programmer there are small chances to succeed.